# Generating a plot from values

Tags: plotting, functions

I have the following function, which generates a value PO for a set of parameters w1,... w7. I would like to make a plot - change w4 alone and plot PO vs w4. How do I do this? In other words, how do I make a function out of this piece of code?

```
Remove["Global`*"]
li = 1000;
w1 = 0.04; w2 = 0.14; w3 = 0.1; w4 = 0.16; w5 = 0.08; w6 = 0.03; w7 = \
0.01; aji = 1; aki = 0.4; ami = 0.8;

w = Solve[{li*(w1 + w4*(1 - v) + w5*(1 - m) + w7*(1 - v)*(1 - m))*u ==
  aji, li*(w4*(1 - u) + w6*(1 - m) + w7*(1 - m)*(1 - u) + w2)*v ==
  aki, li*(w5*(1 - u) + w6*(1 - v) + w7*(1 - v)*(1 - u) + w3)*m ==
  ami}, {u, v, m}];
uu = w[[2, 1, 2]]; vv = w[[2, 2, 2]]; mm = w[[2, 3, 2]];
sol = Solve[{(w1 + w4*(1 - v) + w5*(1 - m) + w7*(1 - v)*(1 - m))*(u + 
        li*A) + 
     li*u*(-w4*B - w5*C - w7*(1 - v)*C - w7*(1 - m)*B) == 
    0, (w2 + w4*(1 - u) + w6*(1 - m) + w7*(1 - u)*(1 - m))*(v + 
        li*B) + 
     li*v*(-w4*A - w6*C - w7*(1 - u)*C - w7*(1 - m)*A) == 
    0, (w3 + w5*(1 - u) + w6*(1 - v) + w7*(1 - u)*(1 - v))*(m + 
        li*C) + 
     li*m*(-w5*A - w6*B - w7*(1 - u)*C - w7*(1 - m)*A) == 0}, {A, 
   B, C}] /. u -> uu /. v -> vv /. m -> mm;
A1 = sol[[1, 1, 2]]; B1 = sol[[1, 2, 2]]; C1 = sol[[1, 3, 2]]; 
DUDL = -(w1*uu + w2*vv + w3*mm + w4*(1 - (1 - vv) (1 - mm)) + 
 w5*(1 - (1 - mm)*(1 - uu)) + w6*(1 - (1 - vv)*(1 - uu)) + 
 w7*(1 - (1 - uu)*(1 - vv)*(1 - mm))) -  li*(w1*A1 + w2*B1 + w3*C1 + w4*(C1) (1 - vv) + w4*(B1) (1 - mm) + 
 w5*(C1) (1 - uu) + w5*(A1) (1 - mm) + w6*(A1) (1 - vv) + 
 w6*(B1) (1 - uu) + 
 w7*((1 - vv) (1 - mm) A1 + (1 - uu) (1 - vv) C1 + (1 - uu) (1 -mm) B1)) + aji/uu*A1 + aki/vv*B1 + ami/mm*C1
PO = -li*(w1*uu + w2*vv + w3*mm + w4*(1 - (1 - vv) (1 - mm)) + 
 w5*(1 - (1 - mm)*(1 - uu)) + w6*(1 - (1 - vv)*(1 - uu)) + 
 w7*(1 - (1 - uu)*(1 - vv)*(1 - mm))) + aji*Log[uu] +  aki*Log[vv] + ami*Log[mm]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since solving the equations symbolically appears to take a very long time, instead I build a function that solves them numerically once a value for w4 is assigned:

```
ClearAll[po]
po[w4_?NumericQ] := 
 Module[{li, w1, w2, w3, w5, w6, w7, aji, aki, ami, w, uu, mm, sol, 
   A1, B1, C1, DUDL},
  li = 1000; w1 = 0.04; w2 = 0.14; w3 = 0.1;(*w4=0.16;*)
  w5 = 0.08; w6 = 0.03; w7 = 0.01;
  aji = 1; aki = 0.4; ami = 0.8;

  w = NSolve[{li*(w1 + w4*(1 - v) + w5*(1 - m) + w7*(1 - v)*(1 - m))*
       u == aji, 
     li*(w4*(1 - u) + w6*(1 - m) + w7*(1 - m)*(1 - u) + w2)*v == aki, 
     li*(w5*(1 - u) + w6*(1 - v) + w7*(1 - v)*(1 - u) + w3)*m == 
      ami}, {u, v, m}];

  uu = w[[2, 1, 2]]; vv = w[[2, 2, 2]]; mm = w[[2, 3, 2]];

  sol = NSolve[{(w1 + w4*(1 - v) + w5*(1 - m) + 
             w7*(1 - v)*(1 - m))*(u + li*A) + 
          li*u*(-w4*B - w5*C - w7*(1 - v)*C - w7*(1 - m)*B) == 
         0, (w2 + w4*(1 - u) + w6*(1 - m) + w7*(1 - u)*(1 - m))*(v + 
             li*B) + 
          li*v*(-w4*A - w6*C - w7*(1 - u)*C - w7*(1 - m)*A) == 
         0, (w3 + w5*(1 - u) + w6*(1 - v) + w7*(1 - u)*(1 - v))*(m + 
             li*C) + 
          li*m*(-w5*A - w6*B - w7*(1 - u)*C - w7*(1 - m)*A) == 0}, {A,
         B, C}] /. u -> uu /. v -> vv /. m -> mm;

  A1 = sol[[1, 1, 2]]; B1 = sol[[1, 2, 2]]; C1 = sol[[1, 3, 2]];

  DUDL = -(w1*uu + w2*vv + w3*mm + w4*(1 - (1 - vv) (1 - mm)) + 
       w5*(1 - (1 - mm)*(1 - uu)) + w6*(1 - (1 - vv)*(1 - uu)) + 
       w7*(1 - (1 - uu)*(1 - vv)*(1 - mm))) - 
    li*(w1*A1 + w2*B1 + w3*C1 + w4*(C1) (1 - vv) + w4*(B1) (1 - mm) + 
       w5*(C1) (1 - uu) + w5*(A1) (1 - mm) + w6*(A1) (1 - vv) + 
       w6*(B1) (1 - uu) + 
       w7*((1 - vv) (1 - mm) A1 + (1 - uu) (1 - vv) C1 + (1 - uu) (1 -
              mm) B1)) + aji/uu*A1 + aki/vv*B1 + ami/mm*C1;

  -li*(w1*uu + w2*vv + w3*mm + w4*(1 - (1 - vv) (1 - mm)) + 
      w5*(1 - (1 - mm)*(1 - uu)) + w6*(1 - (1 - vv)*(1 - uu)) + 
      w7*(1 - (1 - uu)*(1 - vv)*(1 - mm))) + aji*Log[uu] + 
   aki*Log[vv] + ami*Log[mm]
  ]
```

You can then plot `po` as a function of `w4`:

```
Plot[po[w4], {w4, -10, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that `po` seems to be real-valued only for $w4<0$, and complex-valued otherwise. If you are interested int he complex values, you will have to decide whether you want to plot their real and imaginary parts separately (look into `ReIm` for that), or their modulus, etc.